# Why was Quran sent down?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, ahlul-kitab, bible, torah

In several places, the Qur'ān criticizes the Jews (not Christians) for how they misuse their scriptures, accusing them of perverting ( 2:75), concealing (6:61, 2:140) twisting their tongues when they read and even changing the words from their right places

However, the Qur'ān never once says that the written text has been modified, nor that the original scriptures are different than those today. Instead, the Qur'ān says a lot of very positive things about the Jewish and Christian scriptures:
"Let the People of the Gospel judge by what Allah hath revealed therein. If any do fail to judge by (the light of) what Allah hath revealed, they are (no better than) those who rebel" (Sura Maidah 5:47)
"Say: O People of the Book! Ye have no ground to stand upon unless ye stand fast by the Law, the Gospel, and all the revelation that has come to you from your Lord." (Sura Maidah 5:68)

"If you doubt what We have revealed to you, ask those who have read the Scriptures before you." (Sura Yunus 10:94)

"None can change His Words" (Sura Al-An'am 6:115).

If the previous scriptures were not manipulated, then why did Allah sent the Holy Prophet and the Quran down? I am just asking this because everybody says that Quran was sent down because the previous scriptures were changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please quote the verse in full.

> And the word of your Lord has been fulfilled in truth and in justice. None can alter His words, and He is the Hearing, the Knowing. (Qur'an [6:115](http://quran.com/6/115))

It is not talking about altering the scriptures, but it is talking about, "Once a decision has been made by the creator none can dare changing it."

### Authenticity of Scriptures

There have always been [debates](http://www.bing.com/search?q=old%20testament%20authenticity&FORM=AWRE) about the authenticity of the Old Testament, that it is not in it's true form (100 % I mean), but still retains most part of the original meaning. So, literally speaking, the scriptures are manipulated. And New Testament, it is [clear enough](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A16-18&version=NIV), the author either might have took the liberty to add his inferences ('only' son of God), or there might have some problem with narrations (You know, humanly errors).

### Are you in doubt?

> If you doubt what We have revealed to you, ask those who have read the Scriptures before you. (Qur'an 10:94)

Good question, the thing is, even for a damn perfect believer, sometimes when reading Qur'an or sometimes when dealing with Islamic things, we may, due to the influence of cursed Shaitan sometimes think, is this religion true at all, or is this entire thing a fabricated one? For that, God is answering, if you've even the slightest doubt regarding if this is an invented thing, go and ask those [2.2 Billion Christians or 14 million Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations#Adherent_estimates) regarding the signs of Allah, or regarding favors which Allah bestowed on them.

### Why Qur'an?

Now, you can ask...

> then why did Allah sent the Holy Prophet and the Quran down?

If the previous scriptures would suffice to show the signs of Allah, why did he send another Prophet i.e. Muhammad (pbuh)? Well, to answer this, many places in the Qur'an, we can see "we have always been warning" or "we were constantly sending the messengers" or something like that. Warning about what? About the day, when you cannot turn back, and all you can to do is [regret](http://quran.com/89/22-30).

As time passes, the original message of God either got faded away or people got deluded away from the fear of God in any way possible (due to our worst enemy of mankind - Shaitan). Also, people used to consider a part of their scriptures and left a part thereof (e.g. Book 017, Number 4211: [Sahih Muslim](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=hadith%20jews%20adultery%20torah&d=4857682443436245&mkt=en-IN&setlang=en-US&w=STLCILUPsdqhBJJT-t5h5t4H2B04j8mx)). There are many verses in the Qur'an which talk about this in general. So, just again to remind the mankind, God sent his final Prophet i.e. Muhammad (pbuh) along with the complete and perfect message i.e. Qur'an, which he guarantees that he'll protect from no further corruptions.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score -2):

The meaning of ancient books over a thousand years old can easily be perverted by such things as the language changing, lack of a printing press, few scribes that could read, and kings wanting to rewrite holy text (like the King James version). Look at how the word gay has changed it's meaning over the last 50 years. It used to mean happy. If you read a 50 year old book that talked about someone being gay, you could easily misunderstand the true meaning.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but i can't see how this actually answers OP's question!