# What is the proof that Islam is THE truth? How can I have 100% certainty?

Tags: quran, salat, sunni, allah, religion

How do I 100% know for sure that Islam is the truth? How can I be sure that the Islamic worldview - of what Islam says about this world and the afterlife - is true? Can I do better do then just "have faith/iman"? I do feel good after devotional acts of worship but it seems like I need more and these feelings are rather subjective. Is there more than just arguments about the Qur’an (hasn't changed in 1400 years, written in an Arabic that cannot be replicated, scientific argument interpreted to be true)? I am tired of rational arguments as rationality can only come so far, is so malleable, and will not give you a deep sense of spiritual certainty - only logical implications from certain arguments.

How do I make sure that I am not rationalizing to myself that Islam is the true religion, but rather come to a point where I know it is? Because if you want something to be true - then you will rationalize to yourself until you convince yourself that it is true. If you are Christian, then you will rationalize the world through a Christian lens and believe your worldview is the ultimate truth and that Jesus will save you. Likewise in the case of Islam, or any other belief system. I want to be a good Muslim but I need a deeper level of conviction in order to survive in this world.

Comment: Helpful "[Why was Quran sent down?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23904/why-was-quran-sent-down/23915#23915)" in that the "Are you in doubt?" part.

Comment: It seems to be a very significant question, but you'll find reach your repsone if you make your question shorter (Since it could be a broad quetions, and it could be considered as a reason for delay in answering... / Of course the mentioned link (as @servant-of-Wiser presented, can be constructive as well as a helpful context.)

Comment: "How do I make sure that I am not rationalizing to myself that Islam is the true religion, but rather come to a point where I know it is?" You already know where you went to end up - that's a very poor way of looking for truth. The rationalizations and cognitive dissonances offered in favor of Islam are present (in one form or another) in the apologetics for any major religion. Before you look at data, you'll have to figure out what can reasonably be considered evidence.

Answer (score 5):

1. From the viewpoint of Islam, fundamental beliefs i.e Believing in Allah, His oneness, Necessity of sending Prophets and The Day of Resurrection, have to be attained through personal research.(needless to say that Quran **by itself** cannot prove the Existence and Oneness of Allah because it is a kind of circular reasoning)
2. Faith before knowledge is logically meaningless. There is a Hadith from Prophet Mohammad (peace be upon him) saying:

> **واعلم أن أول عبادة الله المعرفة Know that the first of worship of Allah is Ma'rifa (Knowledge)**

3. You have to search for the truth t**o the best of your ability**. However, if you failed to find it in spite of **trying your best**, you will not be held accountable in the hereafter Because of this verse:

> **لا یُکَلِّفُ اللهُ نَفسَاً ِالَّا وُسعَهََا**
>   **Allah dose not task any soul beyond its capacity**(2:286)

4. Philosophically speaking, There exist a "reality" and this "reality" can be perceived. So when there is a contradiction between two statements, one of them is definitely wrong. As a result, if a religion says that there exist more than One God and another religion says that there exists only One God, we can simply make sure that in terms of the first fundamental belief, one of them is **TRUE** and the other is **WRONG**.
5. Facts in Humanitarian sciences are like **numerical order** i.e the fact "A" can only be perceived when it is defined in its right place. Let me give you an example: Number "3" can be "3" **only if** it comes after "2" and before "4". Otherwise it is not number "3". Although, you are capable of putting "3" between "6" and "8" , it is not the real Number "3" but rather Number "7". Number "3" can only be defined when it comes after "2" and before "4". Islamic Teachings are like numbers. Before comprehending the fundamentals, we cannot understand the true definition of "prayers", "fasting", "Hijab" etc.

Therefore, If you start your journey from the very beginning and proceed step by step, you will gradually get a grasp of what you are looking for.

6. When it is proven based on rational reasoning that Allah is All-Sufficient which means He is in need of nothing, those religions holding any beliefs contradicting this verdict, cannot be TRUE religions. For instance, Christianity believes that Jesus is the Son of God. Giving birth to a creature means that birth-giver is composed of parts -as we can see in the process of conception (pregnancy) - and anything comprising parts is in need of its parts, **While** we proved that Allah is in need of nothing!

Comment: Maashallah.........

Comment: "As a result, if a religion says that there exist more than One God and another religion says that there exists only One God, we can simply make sure that in terms of the first fundamental belief, one of them is TRUE and the other is WRONG." This is missing the possibility that there is no god.

Comment: How does this answer: "How do I 100% know for sure that Islam is the truth?"

Answer (score 1):

Islam understands there should be some proof. So the Holly quran presents many reasoning and encourages people to think about them. This is islams main approch.

Also Holy quran talking about many scientific subjects in a special way, so if these scientific subjucts were founded and proofed then you can understand the meaning of Verse, if not you will not be confused.

Even more Islam made some predicts: like When Persia defeated Roman empire, The holy quran predicted that Roman empire will defeat Persians in coming few years. Just Check that.

Note: Holy quran Declared a challenge: "AND IF YOU ARE IN DOUBT ABOUT WHAT WE HAVE SENT DOWN UPON OUR SERVANT [MUHAMMAD], THEN PRODUCE A SURAH THE LIKE THEREOF AND CALL UPON YOUR WITNESS OTHER THAN ALLAH, IF YOU SHOULD BE TRUTHFUL"2:23

Comment: It doesn't talk about any scientific subjects other than that was already known to the nations thousands of years before. Furthermore, half the "scientific" verses that apparently 'describe' today's understanding is not literally but (often a wrong) interpretation. For example, there is no epidemiology in Quran but many muslims believe there is. What the quran DOES talk about is something called epigenesis known to Aristotle a 1000 years back.

Comment: Also, there is a fundamental flaw in the challenge you posted. For that challenge to be 'winnable' a muslim has to believe that the Quran is not perfect and that someone COULD potentially create a surah like any in Quran. In other words, if I present to you any verse from anyone (say Shakespeare), you have already decided that its "lesser" than any verse in the Quran A PRIORI.  So in conclusion, if you already believe that the Quran is the most perfect literature, then you've essentially said "i don't care what verse you give me, I've already decided that it's not as good as any in the Quran"/

Comment: *"needless to say that Quran by itself cannot prove the Existence and Oneness of Allah because it is a kind of circular reasoning"* Do you have a proof for this statement ? If you can't prove anything, it does not necessarily mean that it can't be proven by someone else or sometime later.

Answer (score -1):

If you compare Islam to other religions than you will find out that no other religion is  free of contradictions and errors.

Allah even tells us in the Qur'an that we should point out an error or write a better book if we can, but we will never be able to do that. 
Than I ask you: Is there any other author on the face of the earth which claims that his book is the best and free of any errors? Rather most books start with a prologue which goes like this: "..I tried my best to be as sound as possible.."

Also, there are numerous miracles in the Qur'an:

"..the heavens and the earth were once a joined mass which We spread out.." - Big Bang

"..all life came from water.." - Evolution (However, this does not apply on human beings because there is no sound proof that we were apes at some time)

And many more like that the spherical shape of the earth and the embryologic process.

Things which man from the 7th century in the middle of the desert could not know.

A logical and reasonal person would not choose another religion.